# How to access div in parent from child window

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a div in my parent window where I would like to display new entered records that I have added into the database.

This is inside the parent window:

```
<div id="divTable"></div>
```

This button is inside the child window:

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="updateTable();"/>
```

And this is inside my external javascript file:

```
function updateTable()
{
 if(insertThis()==true)
 {
  alert("Your details have been entered! Please click on 'View' to display all records.");
 }
 //What should I put here?
}//updateTable(w, h)
```

In the same javascript file I have another function that just displays the table(in the parent window for another button) using ajax:

```
function displayTable()
{
 var page = "database.php"
 var parameters = 'action=update';
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if(xmlhttp==null)
  {
   alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
   return false;
  } 
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {      
   document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", page+"?"+parameters, true);
  xmlhttp.send(null); 
}//displayTable()
```

I have another PHP file but that just handles the inserting of queries into the database.

In the child window I have text fields and radio buttons etc to be entered accordingly to the database.

So what should I put in the `updateTable()` function? Should I put the `displayTable()` function there or? I've tried `widnows.opener` and it doesn't seem to work. I've researched online for other examples but they're not dealing with external javascript files so I'm a little confused(or it has nothing to do with that I'm not too sure either).

My desired outcome is that after the user has entered whatever that is required and clicks the `Submit` button, I want the table to be displayed at the parent window immediately. Currently I am using another button in the parent window to display the table. I want to do this because if the user views the table first and then enters new data, after the user exits the user has to click on a button to view the table again. (table to be displayed at `div`)Any solutions?

Note: In my `displayTable()` function I have `document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` so I'm not sure if I should reuse this function.

P.S. I prefer raw javascript solutions as I'm new to it and still learning so I have yet to touch anything on jQuery.

Comment: How did you open the child window? If using window.open, then it is `window.opener.document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=whatever` - PS never use name="submit" in a form. It will break the submit event

Comment: I used window.open to open the window. So about this `window.opener.document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=whatever` if I want this `whatever` to be `displayTable()` is it possible? And I'm not using a form.

Comment: Yes it is possible. `window.opener.displayTable()` will execute the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to reconstruct the table by running that `displayTable();` function again:

```
    function updateTable()
    {
     if(insertThis()==true)
     {
      alert("Your details have been entered! Please click on 'View' to display all records.");
      //Indeed you'd better put it here:
      window.opener.displayTable();
     }
     //What should I put here?

    }//updateTable(w, h)
```

Another recommendation would be: at your parent page change the body tag as follows:

```
 <body onload="displayTable()">
```

And in your child page's script reload that page:

```
function updateTable()
        {
         if(insertThis()==true)
         {
          alert("Your details have been entered! Please click on 'View' to display all records.");
          //Indeed you'd better put it here:
          //window.opener.displayTable();
          window.opener.location.reload();
         }
         //What should I put here?

        }//updateTable(w, h)
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was somewhere along the line.

Comment: Wait no it doesn't, I put it outside the if loop as well but it only displays sometimes, not all the time

Comment: you mean what by if loop? you mean outside `if(insertThis()==true) { ... }` ? you should put there already 'cuz why would you want to update in o record was inserted?

Comment: I meant I tried your method, it makes sense to call it only if a record is inserted. However it doesn't display immediately, not sure why it does for the first time. It's random.

Now I tried it again and it doesn't work. I put it outside the if loop by mistake and it worked sometimes but that was the wrong logic so it's wrong.

Comment: what about the second method I suggested?

Comment: Hm that isn't really my desired out come because it would reload the page, that's why I'm using ajax. Alright I got the problem back, when I click the `Submit` button the table does display together with the new records. However, let's say after I added about 2 records, I add a new record A1. I click `Submit` but A1 doesn't appear. I add a new record B2. Now when I click `Submit`, record A1 and B2 appear in the table. It happens randomly. Does this have to do with any timing or something?

EDIT: On the first button click, sometimes it displays the table, sometimes it doesn't. Not sure why.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, it was my mistake. In my `insertThis()` function I didn't return `true`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have anything in the external javascript that accesses anything of the resulting document and has hardcoded references. At the time the javascript is loaded there isn't anything known about document, it is only known when the document it ready.

If you have anything in the loaded javascript then you need to hand over the resulting/finished object once the document is fully loaded.

So if there is a function that does something to the table you would call it

```
updateTable(opener.document.getElementById('divTable'));
```

The inside the function you use a variable to reference THAT object.
But anyway this should work after the document is loaded

```
window.onload=function(){
    opener.document.getElementById('divTable').style.visibility ="hidden";
    opener.document.getElementById('divTable').innerHTML='Hello, World';
    opener.document.getElementById('divTable').style.visibility ="visible";
}
```

This is in the final html document of the loading child window in a <script> tag.

Comment: Please rewrite the text - if you put the external JS in the body after what it references you can certainly reference the document. Also plain js has `window.onload=function{}` which will execute after page load. OP is asking for non-jQuery solutions